# ng-click calling outer controller from nested ng-controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-init

I'm trying to use angularjs to create a page that does the following:

1. Is initially empty, save for a dropdownlist that is automatically
   populated with apps.
2. upon selecting one of those apps, data about it will be called from
   another controller to the page.

I was successfully able to get the dropdownlist to automatically populate.  however, I'm having issues getting it to make the page with ng-click, which I thing is due to the nested ng-controllers.  Can anyone help me?  Code is below:

My main html page.  Note the use of ng-init:

```
    <div ng-controller="chartsuccessfulapploginsController">
        <div ng-controller="allappsController" ng-init="add()">
            <form name="myForm">
                <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
                <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect" ng-change="chartsuccessfulapploginsController.add(value)">
            <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" ng-init="Index = $index"  value="{{data.availableOptions[Index].id}}" ng-model="APPID" >{{data.availableOptions[Index].name}}</option>
        </select>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <p> {{data}}</p>
            <p> {{data.id[0]}}</p>
            <p> {{data.name[0]}}</p>

            <tt>repeatSelect = {{data.repeatSelect}}</tt><br/>
        </div>
        <p>{{returnCount}}</p>
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <td>{{chartObject.data}}</td>
                <td>{{returnCount}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <div google-chart chart="chartObject" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
    </div>
```

My get all apps controller.  The html page above relies on this to populate the dropdownlist.

```
angular.module('scotchApp').controller('allappsController',['$scope', function($scope){
    var userurl='';
    $scope.add = function(){

        userurl = 'http://localhost:8085/rest/uafapp/appslist';
        var userdata = {};
        var userconfig =
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        };
        var userPostRequest = $.get(userurl, userdata, userconfig);
        var userjson = '{\"USER_DATA_RETRIEVED\" : \"fail\"}';
        userPostRequest.done(function(userdata){

            userjson = JSON.stringify(userdata);
            console.log("userjson :: " + userjson);

            var postResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(userjson);
            $scope.returnName = postResponse['apps'];
            var availableOptionsArray = [];

            for(i = 0; i < postResponse['apps'].length; i++){
                var availableOptions = {};
                availableOptions['id'] = postResponse['apps'][i]['appId'];
                availableOptions['name'] = postResponse['apps'][i]['appName'];
                availableOptionsArray[i] = availableOptions; 
            }
            var returnData = {};
            returnData['repeatSelect'] = null;
            returnData['availableOptions'] = availableOptionsArray;

            $scope.data = returnData;
            console.log($scope.returnData);
            $scope.$apply()
        });

    };
}]);
```

Part of the controller that defines the chart.  It's pretty long, so I didn't include the irrelevant code.

```
   angular.module('scotchApp').controller('chartsuccessfulapploginsController',['$scope','$route','$http','AuthTokenService', function($scope, $route, $http, AuthTokenService){
        var appurl = '';
        var failedappurl= '';

        $scope.add = function(APPID) {

...}
```

Comment: What that part should do?
`value="{{data.availableOptions[Index].id ng-click="chartsuccessfulapploginsController.add(data.availableOptions[Index].id)"}}`

why `ng-click` under `{{}}` expression?

Comment: whoops. edited.  now it should make more sense. @BotanMan

Comment: in any case it's better to use ng-options directive to work with selects properly and ng-model + ng-change to track updates
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `<option>` tag. `ng-click` will not work with the this tag. According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), try using `ng-change` with the select tag as:

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect" ng-change="functionToBeCalledWhenValueChanges(yourBindedElementValue)">
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: unfortuantely, no it didn't.  updating to reflect the change.

Comment: As I can see, you used the `ng-change` with the `<option>`. Use it inside the `<select>` tag.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Did you see that your function `chartsuccessfulapploginsController ` is being called? If yes, which it should, then what is the `value` variable that is being catched inside the function?

Comment: thats not the name of the function.  that's the name of the controller.  add is the name of the function i'm trying to call inside that controller.

Comment: chartsuccessfulapploginscontroller, that is.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the code properly first time. My question is the still the same. Did you see that your function `add` inside the `chartsuccessfulapploginsController ` is being called by debugging in the browser?

Comment: It is not.  That's the issue I'm having.